# How to display images inside the new tab in Python using tkinter

Tags: python, image, tkinter, tabs, display

so I have been trying to display an image viewer app in a new tab from my first one. Wanted that after I click a button a new tab with pictures will appear. Is it possible to do using Tkinter? If so here is the part of the code and I would love any advice:

```
root = tk.Tk()
root.title('chat bot for discord')
def newV():
    set = tk.Tk()
    image1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("-----------------------.jpg"))
    image2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("-----------------------.jpg"))
    image3 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("-----------------------.jpg"))
    image4 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("-----------------------.jpg"))
    image5 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("-----------------------.jpg"))
    image6 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("-----------------------.jpg"))
    image7 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("-----------------------.jpg"))
    image8 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("-----------------------.jpg"))
    image9 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("-----------------------.jpg"))
    image10 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("-----------------------.jpg"))
    image_list = [image1, image2, image3, image4, image5, image6, image7, image8, image9, image10]
    image_label = ttk.Label(image=image1)
    image_label.grid(column=1, row=1, columnspan=3)
    def next(slides_num):
        image_label = ttk.Label(image=image_list[slides_num - 1])
        nextButton = ttk.Button(set, text=">>", command=lambda: next(slides_num + 1))
        if slides_num == 10:
            nextButton = ttk.Button(set, text="done", state=DISABLED)
        image_label.grid(column=1, row=1, columnspan=3)
        functionButton.grid(column=1, row=5)
        nextButton.grid(column=2, row=5)

    functionButton = ttk.Button(set, text="press here")
    nextButton = ttk.Button(set, text=">>", command=lambda: next(2))
    functionButton.grid(column=1, row=5)
    nextButton.grid(column=2, row=5)
    set.mainloop()

newVariablesButton = ttk.Button(root, text="set computer cordinates", command=newV)
newVariablesButton.grid(column=2, row=5)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: for now I did that it will work only after I close my first tab.

Comment: See [Why are multiple instances of Tk discouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48045401/why-are-multiple-instances-of-tk-discouraged). Also, if you want a label inside a particular window, you should make it a child or descendant of that window.

Comment: `set.mainloop()` won't return until the window has been destroyed.

Answer (score 0):

> Wanted that after I click a button a new tab with pictures will appear.

You are using multiple instances of `Tk()` and also the same duplicate of `Label` widgets.

One `Tk()` and `mainloop()` will do entirely script. If you want to open a new window, then you use `Toplevel()`. As requested from Bryan Oakley's comment.

Don't use a `set` and, `next`, it is valid for Python. Use some like underscore.
"If you want to open a new window, then you use Toplevel()".

- `top = tk.Toplevel()` instead of `set = tk.Tk()`.

As you said, "I wanted that after I click a button a new tab with pictures would appear".

You are missing root window in `newV()` function.

- On line 26, `image_label = ttk.Label(top,...)` instead of
  `image_label = ttk.Label(...)`. You don't need keyword `image=`
- On line 19, comment out and replace `.configure`. should be
  `image_label.config(image=image_list[slides_num - 1])`.
- On lines 20, 23, 24 and 25, move to `newV()` function.
- On line 22, add `tk.` prefix to `state=tk.DISABLED`
- On line 31, comment out `#set.mainloop()`.

Snippet modified your script:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from PIL import Image,ImageTk

root=tk.Tk()

root.title('chat bot for discord')
def newV():
    top = tk.Toplevel()
    image1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("p1.png"))
    image2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("p2.png"))
    image3 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("p3.png"))
    image4 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("p4.png"))
    image5 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("p5.png"))
    image6 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("p6.png"))
    image7 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("p7.png"))
    image8 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("p8.png"))
    image9 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("p9.png"))
    image10 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("p10.png"))
    
    image_list = [image1, image2, image3,
                  image4, image5, image6,
                  image7, image8, image9,
                  image10]
    
    image_label = ttk.Label(top, image=image1)
    
    functionButton = ttk.Button(top, text="press here")
    
    nextButton = ttk.Button(top, text=">>", command=lambda: _next(2))
    
    functionButton.grid(column=1, row=5)
    nextButton.grid(column=2, row=5)
    image_label.grid(column=1, row=1, columnspan=3)

    
    def _next(slides_num):
        image_label.config(image=image_list[slides_num - 1])
        nextButton.configure(command=lambda: _next(slides_num + 1))
        if slides_num == 10:
            nextButton.configure(text="done", state=tk.DISABLED)

         
newVariablesButton = ttk.Button(root, text="set computer cordinates", command=newV)
newVariablesButton.grid(column=2, row=5)

root.mainloop()
```

Screenshot, open main window:

[image]

Screenshot #1. Opens on a new window when first clicked:

[image]

Screenshot #1, when the second clicked:

[image]

Screenshot #1, `if slides_num == 10`. You will see the disabled button:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If your goal use of a tabbed GUI and not the experience of writing it yourself, Tkinter has a widget that provides it:

see:  ttk.Notebook

You create the ttk.Notebook widget then add child widgets (typically frames) inside the Notebook.  Each child widget gets a tab with an assigned names along the top of the notebook.

Click the tabs to change the visible child widget - I think that's what you're trying to do.

It also provides a virtual event that you can use in order to execute code when the user selects a different tab.

There are several basic tutorials available on the internet.

Comment: OP not talking about notebook.   He meant "How to display images inside the new tab". The new tab meant is Toplevel()